# PHP Server unable to find real IP

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running an Elastic Beanstalk Environment, with a load balancer, and instances which are running a symfony2 application.

I cannot get the real visitor IP address, $request->getClientIP() returns null, if i set it to trust proxies in app.php, like this:

Request::setTrustedProxies(array($request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')));

I get weird multicast addresses:

172.31.25.85

172.31.25.85

172.31.42.183

Etc..

Here is my SSL termination in ssl.conf

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:80/
ProxyPreserveHost on
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" early
```

Here is my dump of $_SERVER

```
Array (
    [REDIRECT_COMPOSER_HOME] => /root
    [REDIRECT_PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT] => 512M
    [REDIRECT_PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME] => 60
    [REDIRECT_PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS] => Off
    [REDIRECT_PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS] =>
    [REDIRECT_PHP_ALLOW_URL_FOPEN] => On
    [REDIRECT_PHP_ZLIB_OUTPUT_COMPRESSION] => Off
    [REDIRECT_PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /web/
    [REDIRECT_PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE] => UTC
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [COMPOSER_HOME] => /root
    [PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT] => 512M
    [PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME] => 60
    [PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS] => Off
    [PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS] =>
    [PHP_ALLOW_URL_FOPEN] => On
    [PHP_ZLIB_OUTPUT_COMPRESSION] => Off
    [PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /web/
    [PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE] => UTC
    [HTTP_HOST] => c.filtered.com
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.5
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br
    [HTTP_REFERER] => https://c.filtered.com/da/c/filtered
    [HTTP_COOKIE] => PHPSESSID=gcrn9sfbq1rhkactkau6s5fbn2; hl=da; returning_visitor=1; __utma=84468683.1790758543.1493197744.1493197744.1493207849.2; __utmc=84468683; __utmz=84468683.1493207849.2.2.utmcsr|utmccn=(
    referral
    )|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/da/; PAPVisitorId=2491e88a40a6a8d0b2918dOIatw1xtp9; __utmb=84468683.1.10.1493207849; __utmt=1
    [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => https
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 172.31.25.85
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST] => c.filtered.com
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER] => c.filtered.com
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => Keep-Alive
    [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 253
    [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] =>
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
    [SERVER_NAME] => c.filtered.com
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html/web/
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] =>
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html/web/
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => root@localhost
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/html/web/app.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 54638
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /da/c/filtered
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => POST
    [QUERY_STRING] =>
    [REQUEST_URI] => /da/c/filtered
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /app.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /app.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1493208003.205
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1493208003
)
```

Comment: Site note: `print_r()` inserts line feeds. You probably need to check the HTML source to see them (Ctrl+U in some Windows browsers).

Comment: This is inserted via a logger

Comment: Alright, I've used http://phillihp.com/toolz/php-array-beautifier/php-beautifier-v2/ then

Comment: You should check your whole stack and find where the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header is removed. May be the ssl terminator, may be the load balancer, may be a proxy cache...

Comment: I think i found it

Comment: For some reason i cannot install a proper apache logger, but i think the issue is that i am using Amazon Load Balancer and forwarding via TCP, it seems apache is unable to read the source IP, but nginx can

Comment: There is a fix for apache, but compiling the source module is not working for me https://technobcn.wordpress.com/2014/12/06/apache-proxy-protocol-for-amazon-elb-elastic-load-balancing/

Comment: So i will be replicating my prod env and replacing apache with nginx

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function which get real ip, sometime `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` not show real ip so need to customize to get real ip.

```
function getRealIP()
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
        } elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        } elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"];
        } elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        } elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"];
        } else {
            $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }

        // Strip any secondary IP etc from the IP address
        if (strpos($ip, ',') > 0) {
            $ip = substr($ip, 0, strpos($ip, ','));
        }
        return $ip;
    }
```

Comment: this isn't what the OP asking about

Comment: There is no real IP present, please take a look

Comment: If the IP is not present in the $_SERVER dump, it is not there

Comment: it will get real ip and tested.

Comment: No, it will not, the real ip is not in the $_SERVER dump, it is getting removed somewhere along the line via reverse proxies, please understand the question before answering with garbage.